# How to access elements from a CMap?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

Can someone please enlighten me about how to get a particular element based on a particular key. Say If i have a CMap ButtonProp; 
and now i want to access the property for any int value supplied, how to do that? 
P.S. First time with CMap. Does "ButtonProp.Lookup(int)" suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options:

If you *know* that the element exists, you can use [`CMap::operator[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htba4sd6.aspx):

Otherwise, you should use [`CMap::Lookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zshx6yzt.aspx), but the usage is different than that in your question.

Suppose you start with

```
CMap<int,int,CPoint,CPoint> myMap;

myMap.InitHashTable(257);
```

To find the element corresponding to 3, you would use

```
myMap[3]
```

or

```
CPoint ret;
bool found = myMap.Lookup(3, ret);
```

If `found` is `true`, then `ret` is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code snippet that demonstrates the usage of `CMap` container:

```
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, int, int> NameToValueMap;

CString sKey(_T("Test"));
int nValue = 10;        
NameToValueMap[sKey] = nValue;


if (NameToValueMap.IsEmpty())
    return;

int nVal;
if (NameToValueMap.Lookup(sKey, nVal))
{
    // TO DO: do stuff with value here
}
```